# MICE Error: dims [xx] do not match the length of object [xx]

Tags: r, r-mice

I'm trying to impute many (120) columns of a dataset with 205 columns total. I am repeatedly encountering an error that my dimensions do not match. The imputation runs when I specify one imputation method for the entire dataset, but it's not appropriate given that I have multiple types of variables. Ideally, the complete (no NA) columns would not be imputed, but would be used as predictors.

A look at my variables:

```
> str(PRNdf3)
tibble [1,202 × 205] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ sex                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ cvd                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ neuro                : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ htn                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ cad                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ hf                   : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ valv                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ copd                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ asthma               : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ osa                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ current_smoking      : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ former_smoking       : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 ...
 $ cancer               : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ gerd                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ renal                : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ crf                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ liver                : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ diabetes             : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ thyroid              : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ etoh                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ b_ag                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ atrovent             : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ inh_steroids         : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ po_steroids          : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ leuko_inhib          : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ antib                : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ b_blocker            : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ aspirin              : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ statin               : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ ca_antag             : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ acei                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ara                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ nitrate              : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ diuretic             : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ insulin              : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ other_diabetes       : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ppi                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ h2_inhib             : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ surg_code            : Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 4 7 1 1 3 3 ...
 $ emergency            : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ epidural             : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ spinal               : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ regional             : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ desflurane           : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ sevoflurane          : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ isoflurane           : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ n2o                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ propofol             : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ dep_nmba             : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ nondep_nmba          : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ nondep_nmba_drug     : Factor w/ 18 levels "CIAT/ROCUR","CIS-ATRACURIUM",..: 12 7 12 7 7 NA 12 7 7 7 ...
 $ nmba_monitoring      : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ nmba_monitoring_loc  : Factor w/ 25 levels "ANKLE;RI","AVAILABL",..: 22 22 22 22 22 NA 22 22 22 22 ...
 $ rev_nmba             : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ pain_protocol        : Factor w/ 11 levels "CELECOXIB&ACETAMINOPHEN",..: 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ resp_failure         : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ po_intub             : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ards                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ pneumonia            : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ pneumothorax         : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ atelectasis          : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ pleural_effusion     : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ bronchospasm         : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ po_cannula           : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ po_facemask          : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ pomv                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ po_ninv              : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ po_peak_wbc          : num [1:1202] 13.9 13.2 7.2 20.9 14.2 ...
 $ inhospital_mortality : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ LR                   : num [1:1202] 1000 1100 2250 3000 500 1200 2900 1500 1250 250 ...
 $ age                  : num [1:1202] 60 89 55 81 61 72 40 57 76 53 ...
 $ albumin5             : num [1:1202] 1250 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ dbp_q1               : num [1:1202] 46 57 53 57 56 68 66 63 52 54 ...
 $ dbp_q2               : num [1:1202] 53 60 65.5 62 60.5 72 72 66 56 56 ...
 $ dbp_q3               : num [1:1202] 60 67 78.5 68 66 75 79 69 61 58 ...
 $ desat_mins           : num [1:1202] 0 5 0 0 11 2 0 0 9 0 ...
 $ ebl                  : num [1:1202] 1300 400 0 550 250 30 1250 50 75 25 ...
 $ ephedrine            : num [1:1202] 0 15 0 0 20 0 20 5 35 0 ...
 $ etco2_q1             : num [1:1202] 33 33 37 33 33 33 36 34 35 35 ...
 $ etco2_q2             : num [1:1202] 37 34 40 34 35 34 37 35 36 35 ...
 $ etco2_q3             : num [1:1202] 38 36 41 35 38 35 39 37 38.5 36 ...
 $ fentanyl             : num [1:1202] 1058 250 100 250 250 ...
 $ ffp                  : num [1:1202] 450 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ fio2_q1              : num [1:1202] 39 57 57 54 44 38 54 53 42 28 ...
 $ fio2_q2              : num [1:1202] 48 57 58 54 46 39 54 56 49 31 ...
 $ fio2_q3              : num [1:1202] 56 58 92 54 47 43 59 96 51 32 ...
 $ glyco                : num [1:1202] 0.6 0.4 0.6 0.4 0.6 0 0.4 0.6 0.4 0.8 ...
 $ height               : num [1:1202] 1.75 1.68 1.6 1.78 1.73 ...
 $ hospital_days        : num [1:1202] 5 7 2 8 19 6 4 32 5 6 ...
 $ hr_q1                : num [1:1202] 62 68 51 92 67 83 92 67 60 81 ...
 $ hr_q2                : num [1:1202] 72 70 58 102 68 87 96.5 69 65.5 84 ...
 $ hr_q3                : num [1:1202] 80 73 66 111 70 90 105 71 75 88 ...
 $ hydromorphone        : num [1:1202] 0 4 0.6 2 0 0 1.2 1 0.8 1 ...
 $ icu_intermediate_days: num [1:1202] 2 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 4.5 5.5 ...
 $ ketamine             : num [1:1202] 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ low_mbp_mins         : num [1:1202] 10 1 9 3 2 2 3 1 4 0 ...
 $ low_sbp_mins         : num [1:1202] 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ mbp_q1               : num [1:1202] 74 78 69.5 75 75.5 82 81 80 73.5 74 ...
 $ mbp_q2               : num [1:1202] 83 85 87 81 86 88 89.5 83.5 81 78 ...
  [list output truncated]
```

When I specify predictive mean matching for the entire dataset, the imputation runs but with over 4,000 logged events. I want to specify the appropriate method for each variable.

```
> imp0 <- mice(PRNdf3, maxit = 0)
Warning message:
Number of logged events: 3 
> meth <- imp0$meth
> meth
                  sex                   cvd                 neuro                   htn                   cad                    hf                  valv 
                   ""                    ""                    ""                    ""              "logreg"              "logreg"              "logreg" 
                 copd                asthma                   osa       current_smoking        former_smoking                cancer                  gerd 
             "logreg"                    ""                    ""              "logreg"              "logreg"                    ""              "logreg" 
                renal                   crf                 liver              diabetes               thyroid                  etoh                  b_ag 
                   ""                    ""              "logreg"                    ""                    ""              "logreg"                    "" 
             atrovent          inh_steroids           po_steroids           leuko_inhib                 antib             b_blocker               aspirin 
                   ""                    ""                    ""                    ""                    ""                    ""                    "" 
               statin              ca_antag                  acei                   ara               nitrate              diuretic               insulin 
                   ""                    ""              "logreg"                    ""                    ""                    ""                    "" 
       other_diabetes                   ppi              h2_inhib             surg_code             emergency              epidural                spinal 
                   ""                    ""                    ""                    ""              "logreg"              "logreg"              "logreg" 
             regional            desflurane           sevoflurane            isoflurane                   n2o              propofol              dep_nmba 
             "logreg"              "logreg"              "logreg"              "logreg"              "logreg"              "logreg"              "logreg" 
          nondep_nmba      nondep_nmba_drug       nmba_monitoring   nmba_monitoring_loc              rev_nmba         pain_protocol          resp_failure 
             "logreg"             "polyreg"              "logreg"             "polyreg"              "logreg"             "polyreg"              "logreg" 
             po_intub                  ards             pneumonia          pneumothorax           atelectasis      pleural_effusion          bronchospasm 
             "logreg"                    ""                    ""                    ""                    ""                    ""                    "" 
           po_cannula           po_facemask                  pomv               po_ninv           po_peak_wbc  inhospital_mortality                    LR 
             "logreg"              "logreg"              "logreg"                    ""                 "pmm"              "logreg"                 "pmm" 
                  age              albumin5                dbp_q1                dbp_q2                dbp_q3            desat_mins                   ebl 
                "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                    ""                 "pmm" 
            ephedrine              etco2_q1              etco2_q2              etco2_q3              fentanyl                   ffp               fio2_q1 
                   ""                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm" 
              fio2_q2               fio2_q3                 glyco                height         hospital_days                 hr_q1                 hr_q2 
                "pmm"                 "pmm"                    ""                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm" 
                hr_q3         hydromorphone icu_intermediate_days              ketamine          low_mbp_mins          low_sbp_mins                mbp_q1 
                "pmm"                    ""                    ""                    ""                    ""                    ""                 "pmm" 
               mbp_q2                mbp_q3              morphine           neostigmine      nondep_nmba_dose  nondep_nmba_lastdose            pacu_hours 
                "pmm"                 "pmm"                    ""                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm" 
     pacu_ready_hours               peep_q1               peep_q2               peep_q3         phenylephrine                pip_q1                pip_q2 
                "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                    ""                 "pmm"                 "pmm" 
               pip_q3            plasmalyte             platelets       po_cannula_days                  prbc              preop_hb            preop_spo2 
                "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm" 
         remifentanil                 rr_q1                 rr_q2                 rr_q3                saline                sbp_q1                sbp_q2 
                   ""                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm" 
               sbp_q3               spo2_q1               spo2_q2               spo2_q3             sucx_dose               temp_q1               temp_q2 
                "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm" 
              temp_q3                    uo           vasopressin                 vt_q1                 vt_q2                 vt_q3                weight 
                "pmm"                 "pmm"                    ""                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm" 
           sufentanil            mean_ap_q1            mean_ap_q2            mean_ap_q3           plateaup_q1           plateaup_q2           plateaup_q3 
                   ""                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm" 
          oxymorphone                  site                   BMI                   PBW              VTadj_Q1              VTadj_Q2              VTadj_Q3 
                "pmm"                    ""                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm" 
            deltaP_q1             deltaP_q2             deltaP_q3        regional_block              surg_dur            anesth_dur      Neostigmine_MGKG 
                "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                    ""                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm" 
   Neostigmine_micgkg                anemia     crystalloid_fluid         colloid_fluid               prbc_ml                ffp_ml          platelets_ml 
                   ""                    ""                 "pmm"                    ""                    ""                    ""                    "" 
             prbc_ind               ffp_ind         platelets_ind      remifentanil_min               uo_kghr                PPC_rx              pomv_new 
                   ""                    ""                    ""                    ""                 "pmm"                    ""                    "" 
       poIntub_noards          poIntub_ards             PPC_dx_rx    po_cannuladays_gt1   po_facemaskdays_gt1      cannula_facemask                PPC_dx 
                   ""                    ""                    ""                    ""                    ""                    ""                    "" 
        LargeVtadj_q2          LargePEEP_q2          LargeFiO2_q2               PPC_num              ventmode                ME_mcg             F_mcgkghr 
                   ""                    ""                    ""                    ""             "polyreg"                 "pmm"                 "pmm" 
            S_mcgkghr             H_mcgkghr             O_mcgkghr             M_mcgkghr            blood_prod               PO_Xray      phenylephrineIND 
                "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                 "pmm"                    ""                    ""                    "" 
         ephedrineIND        vasopressinIND          F_mcgkghrIND          s_mcgkghrIND          h_mcgkghrIND          m_mcgkghrIND             ME_mcgIND 
                   ""                    ""                    ""                    ""                    ""                    ""                    "" 
              remiIND           ketamineIND 
                   ""                    ""
```

When I do it this way, variables with no NAs are not imputed, and all other variables have the appropriate method. However, I keep getting the error:

```
> imp3 <- mice(PRNdf3, maxit = 20, meth = meth, print = TRUE, seed = 107)

 iter imp variable
  1   1  cad  hfError in mice.impute.logreg(y = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  dims [product 264] do not match the length of object [265]
In addition: Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: In beta + rv %*% rnorm(ncol(rv)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

What could be causing this error? All variables are either left out of the imputation or have an appropriate method specified, so there shouldn't be a mismatch in the dimensions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This output tells you that `hf` cannot be imputed with the `logreg` method. What's in the `loggedEvents`? And what happens if you change the variable to numeric and the method to `pmm`?